# Asymptotic running time of isPrime algorithm in terms of the input size n

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an isPrime function below:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if(n == 1) return false;
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i) {
        if(n % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My questions are:

1. what is the asymptotic running time of this algorithm in terms of
   the size ||n|| of input?
2. Explain why the running time obtained in
   "1" is **exponential** in the size of input.

What I do not understand here is why this algorithm is exponential.

> Note: This question was asked in an algorithm exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we can see that the algorithm is looping over a single statement (the if statement) for up to `sqrt(n)` times. So its running time is proportional to the square root of the value of `n`.

Now, the question asks the running time **with respect to the size of the input**, not the value of the input. Input size is the amount of storage used to store the input. In this case the input is just a single number `n`.

A number `n`, when represented in binary (this argument still holds when it's represented in any other base), has `log n` bits, and so doing the loop `sqrt(n)` times is exponential of the size of the input, since the input size is `log n` and `sqrt(n) = exp(C * log n)` with `C = 0.5`.

Therefore we have the algorithm shown is exponential in the size of the input.

Comment: Hi there @justhalf, though you wrote a comprehensive answer but I am having trouble comprehending it. Could you please elaborate it further...

Comment: I mean take an example for n and then explain :)